# Why won't UILabel update in Apps Amuck MinutesToMidnight iPhone tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using xcode and interface builder 3.2.5, and am trying to implement the first app from the http://appsamuck.com/day1.html website. I believe that I have followed all of the instructions, but the app fails to work. The app teaches how to create a label called countdownLabel (on top of a black background) within the view and connects the countdownLabel through the Interface Builder. The app starts a timer within the appDelegate:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

...
}

On each timer tick, the appDelegate onTimer method calls a viewController method to update the countdownLabel with a string that identifies the hours, minutes and seconds before midnight. When the app runs, the countdownLabel never updates. Instead, the background turns white.

When I set breakpoints, I see that the timer is running properly (i.e. a periodic call to onTimer occurs) and calling the method to update the countdownLabel. However, before the first timer event ever occurs, a call to the ViewController method "loadView" is made:

- (void)loadView {
  [countdownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:128.0]];
  countdownLabel.text = @"I0A0IN6";
  }

When I stop in this method, I see that the content of the countdownLabel is 0x0. If I continue the execution to a breakpoint within the appDelegate onTimer method, the screen turns white. This method then calls a method to update the countdownLabel, but the label never changes (probably because the value of the countdownLabel remains a value of 0x0).

Why is the countdownLabel 0x0? Is there some initialization or connection that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you did these steps correctly (linking the IBOutlet in File's Owner to the label in Interface Builder)

> Now we need to wire up the Label in
>   Interface Builder to the UILabel in
>   the class file
>
> Reopen Interface Builder
>
> Select the Label in the View or in
>   Document Window
>
> Click: Tools -> Connection Inspector
>
> Move your mouse cursor over the empty
>   circle to the right of text "New
>   Referencing Outlet" (the circle will
>   change to a Plus(+))
>
> Mouse Click then drag the Plus (+) to
>   "File's Owner" in Document Window
>
> When you release select countdownLabel
>   in the popup list
>
> Click: File -> Save then close
>   Interface Builder

Comment: Ned, Thanks. Yes, I did verify that this was done properly. But still no luck getting this to work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Ah, it's probably because you're setting font stuff in - (void)loadView, not - (void)viewDidLoad. Providing a definition for - (void)loadView makes it so it skips loading the nib, so you're just left with a white screen. See if changing that method does the trick.

Comment: Oh my gosh. You are absolutely right. That was a painful lesson. Thanks so much.